# How to prevent validation style from affecting tooltip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I used the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278508/get-visual-feedback-from-qvalidator) to give users a signal regarding the quality of their input for a `QLineEdit`. The trouble is that my `QToolTip` has incorporated this same style which is not ideal.

Here is the validator

```
def handleValidationChange(self, state):
    if state == QtGui.QValidator.Invalid:
        colour = 'white'
    elif state == QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate:
        colour = 'yellow'
    elif state == QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable:
        colour = 'lightgreen'
   
    self.nameLineEdit.setStyleSheet('background-color: %s' % colour)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, lambda: self.nameLineEdit.setStyleSheet(''))
```

Within the `app.setStyleSheet` I try to make it so the tool tip gets a different style, but it ends up matching the validation style, if I hover over the line-edit while an entry is made.

```
 app.setStyleSheet('''\
    QToolTip {background-color: lightblue !important;}
    '''
    )
```

Does anyone know how separate out the line-edit style with the validation from the `QToolTip` style? In this screen capture, the line-edit, and tool-tip background colors match.

[image: qtooltip matches validation color]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must indicate which class (or classes) the stylesheet affects, if not, it is equivalent to using QWidget as a class so it will be applied to all its children and the tooltip.

The solution is:

```py
self.edit.setStyleSheet(
    "QLineEdit{border: 3px solid %s} QToolTip{background-color: lightblue}"
    % colour
)
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(
    1000,
    lambda: self.edit.setStyleSheet("QToolTip{background-color: lightblue}"),
)
```